# How to user a custom IEqualityComparer to compare a collection?

Tags: c#

I am attempting to test for List equality using a custom IEqualityComparer and my implementation isn't working.

```
var expected = new List<Space> { new Space(7, 7, 'a'), new Space(7, 8, 'b') };
var result = new List<Space> { new Space(7, 7, 'a'), new Space(7, 8, 'b') };

        //These asserts pass
Assert.That(SpaceTileEqualityComparer.Instance.Equals(expected[0], result[0]));
Assert.That(SpaceTileEqualityComparer.Instance.Equals(expected[1], result[1]));
Assert.That(expected.Count() == result.Count());
Assert.That(result.Except(expected, SpaceCoordsEqualityComparer.Instance).Count(), Is.EqualTo(0));

        //This assert fails
Assert.That(result.Except(expected, SpaceTileEqualityComparer.Instance).Count(), Is.EqualTo(0));
```

As you can see I have two lists made up of two Space type objects each. I have two custom implementations of IEqualityCompaper: SpaceCoordsEqualityComparer checks the first two values in Space objects for equality. SpaceTileEqualityComparer checks three values for equality.

The first two asserts are there to prove that SpaceTileEqualityComparer is doing it's job. Each element in each List is considered equal to its counterpart. The third assert is just to assure myself that nothing bizarre is happening with the lists and that no other elements are sneaking into them. The fourth assert is how I had originally tested for list equality. I am creating a new list by using the Except() method to subtract the common elements between the lists from the first list and then asserting that the new list has a Count of 0. And this also is working with the custom comparer that only tests the first two values in the Space objects. However, when I use the custom comparer that checks three elements the Except method does not subtract any elements and returns a list of Count 2.

So, from what I can tell the custom comparers work. The lists are equal. Using Except() with a custom comparer to create a new list of no length works. But when I put all those elements together something goes wrong.

Here's the two comparers:

```
public class SpaceCoordsEqualityComparer : EqualityComparer<Space>
{
    private static readonly SpaceCoordsEqualityComparer _instance = new SpaceCoordsEqualityComparer();

    public static SpaceCoordsEqualityComparer Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    public override bool Equals(Space a, Space b)
    {
        if (a == null && b == null)
            return true;
        if (a == null || b == null)
            return false;

        return a.GetCoords().Equals(b.GetCoords());
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(Space obj)
    {
        return obj.GetX().GetHashCode() ^ obj.GetY().GetHashCode();
    }
}
public class SpaceTileEqualityComparer : EqualityComparer<Space>
{
    private static readonly SpaceTileEqualityComparer _instance = new SpaceTileEqualityComparer();

    public static SpaceTileEqualityComparer Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    public override bool Equals(Space a, Space b)
    {
        if (a == null && b == null)
            return true;
        if (a == null || b == null)
            return false;

        return (a.GetCoords().Equals(b.GetCoords())) && (a.GetTileLetter() == b.GetTileLetter());
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(Space obj)
    {
        return obj.GetCoords().GetHashCode() ^ obj.GetTile().GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: For any one looking in the future I solved the bug. It turns out I was overriding my the GetHashCode method in the second custom comparer in an improper way. After fixing that code my implementation of using the custom IEqualityComparer with List.Except worked.

Comment: you might want to put this into an answer and answer your own question.